# Send UDP Requests on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a NodeJS application which I want to send UDP request to multiple servers at the same time. Here is my sample code.

```
    const dgram = require('dgram');
    const urlParser = require('url').parse;
    const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
    const url = urlParser("my url goes here");
    var _msg = "My message";

    socket.send(_msg, 0, _msg.length, url.port, url.host, () => {});
        socket.on('message', msg => {
            console.log('Message is: ' + msg);
        })
```

I can manage to send a request to one server at a time. But I don't know how to send the same requset to multiple servers at once. I tried something like this

```
var servers = ["server1", "server2", "server3", ...];

for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++){
     var url = urlParser(servers[i]);

      socket.send(_msg, 0, _msg.length, url.port, url.host, () => {});
          socket.on('message', msg => {
              console.log('Message is: ' + msg);
          })

}
```

This is getting MaxListenersExceededWarning. And I think this is not the correct way to do this. I am an absolute beginner to JavaScript and Node.JS. Please help me to solve this

Comment: It generally is a bad practice to create event handlers in a loop - but you found that out :-).  You only have one `socket` object declared - that means you only need one listener. Move the listener code outside the loop. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.The actual problem here is not about the listener. When I run this code it wait while one server is responded. If first severer of the array is not responded, loop is not continue to next server. I want to modify this code to make the request to all servers at the same time whether one server is responded or not.

Comment: Sounds as if you should set the broadcast option to try and send the to the host's broadcast address.

Comment: This: https://nrempel.com/posts/using-udp-multicast-with-nodejs/